# Create Description for My Nuget Package in TFS

Tags: tfs, nuget-package

I can add description by using nuget.exe but I want to do that in Nuget Packager step in TFS. But I cant find out any "description" paramter.

for example

[image]

you can see in the description part, only written "description". I want to write some comment about this version in TFS or maybe in the project.

How i can do that easily?

in TFS, the packager looks like

[image]

Is there any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a .nuspec file containing the metadata.
You can find more information on creating a package here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package

Once there is a nuspec file, you can change the description from the build step in the additional build properties as such:

```
Description="This is a great package"
```

This does require you to replace the description in the nuspec file with a token. In this example it would be:

```
<description>$Description$</description>
```

This is described in the help page for this build step:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/package/nuget-packager

Comment: First one did not work. The second one i already know but i want to do that in TFS. So in TFS log, its like that C:\Build\externals\nuget\NuGet.exe pack "C:\Builds\2\s\HelperLibrary\HelperLibrary.csproj" -OutputDirectory "C:\Builds\2\s" -Properties Configuration=release;Description="This is a great package" -IncludeReferencedProjects 
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.

Comment: The build properties replace tokens in the nuspec file, so they require a nuspec file. You can create a nuspec file and place tokens to be able to control this from TFS. I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: yes the problem how to create nuspec file with TFS? I know that i can do that manually but i want TFS to do this thing, i jwant to give only the description parameter in TFS. This nuspec file is created by the packer so as i understand, I have to create this and rest of it, TFS's work? But why i cannot give the description as parameter in TFS

Comment: Because the nuget pack command line does not offer functionality for this. You need the nuspec file to contain the data

Comment: This is a full automatic way, it just requires a specification file in your project. If you are satisfied with the answer, please mark it as answer.